# Ruby: Check if all objects' attribute within array are equal

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array which contain objects. I would like to check if all elements (objects) within the array have similar attribute value.

So, if we have the following array

```
array = [clone1, clone2, clone3]
```

clone1, clone2, and clone3 are objects of class clone. They contain an attribute called "source". I want to check if clone1, clone2, and clone3 have the same "source" value.

this is an example of clone object

```
#<CloneTool:0x007ff968a2f7b0 @nline=["10"], @sim=["100"], @ds=[".."], @dstart=[".."], @dend=[".."], @hs=[".."], @hstart=[".."], @hend=[".."]>
```

So I want to check if array has equal value for @ds.

Any thought?

Comment: `ary.all? {|elem| elem.source == ary.first.source}`

Comment: `ary.any? {|elem| elem.source != ary.first.source} # find one that NOT equal`

Comment: @gaussblurinc: normally, you want to be explicit about your intentions. This, it seems, he intends to check if all elements have the same value. Checking if any elements have different value is masking the intention somewhat.

Comment: can you give us an example of what a clone object looks like?

Comment: @gaussblurinc There is no reason to introduce a negation when you can do without it.

Comment: @sawa: there is a reason, though. `any?` here will short-circuit.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, you are right, but `all?` consumes `O(n)` iterations everytime, while upper bound for `any?` is `O(n)` in bad cases. but, of course, it doesn't matter for small amount of data. And, of course, `(x and y) == not (not x or not y)`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev In terms of short-circuit, it does not make difference. `all?` short-circuits when the block evaluates to `false`, and `any?` does when the block evaluates to `true`. And since the block for the latter is the negation of that of the former, they will short-circuit on precisely the same examples.

Comment: @sawa: indeed, my bad.

Comment: @gaussblurinc: sawa reminds us that `all?` short-circuits too :)

Comment: @JeffPrice I added an example.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, true, my fault :)

Answer (score 2):

```
array.map(&:source).uniq.length == 1
```

or

```
array.group_by(&:source).length == 1
```

Comment: it gave "wrong argument type String (expected Proc) (TypeError)"

Comment: @arwa: must be you messed up with replicating this line. If your elements have method `source`, it should work

Comment: This works for me, my guess is his clone object is different than we think it is and this is causing his failure. Instead of map(&:source) it might need to be map{|x| x[:source]} or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.uniq(&:source).size == 1
```

If there is no accessor for `@source`:

```
arr.uniq { |e| e.instance_variable_get(:@source) }.size == 1
```

Answer (score -3):

```
array.map{|x| x.source == array[0].source}.all?
```

Comment: it doesn't work for special arrays. for example, array with one element

Comment: @gaussblurinc It does work. In that case, the result would be trivially `true`. Note that `[].all? # => true`.

Comment: Usage of `all?` here is weird. "all" what?

Comment: @sawa: but `map` is responsible for preparing data for `all?` here.